# IE: Back and Refresh buttons behave differently on onbeforeunload event and url hashtag changes

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, onbeforeunload

Steps:

1. Open a website in ie11(e.g. www.baidu.com), in the console, type:

   ```
   window.onbeforeunload = function(){return "aaa";}
   ```
2. press **Refresh button**, an alert pops up, choose stay on this page
3. in the console, type:

   ```
   top.location = location.href+"#?id=aaa"
   ```

   now the url should be www.baidu.com/#?id=aaa
4. press **Back button**, works fine, return to www.baidu.com
5. press **Back button** again, an alert pops up, choose stay on this page.
6. in the console, type:

   ```
   top.location = location.href+"#?id=aaa"
   ```

   now the url should be www.baidu.com/#?id=aaa
7. press **Back button**

   **Expected**: return to www.baidu.com, Chrome Opera Firefox all return to www.baidu.com

   **Actual Result**: an alert pops up, if you choose leave this page, you will be redirecting to the page before www.baidu.com.

How can I resolve this, I want to return to www.baidu.com like Chrome does.

Please help.

I've tried using history.pushState, it works fine in ie11, but ie9 doesn't have history.pushState.